# Changing one date to another date format using LocalDate

Tags: java, spring-boot, date, timezone

I have the following input as a

```
Map<String,String>

1) MM dd yyyy = 08 10 2019
2) dd MM yyyy = 10 05 2019
3) dd MM yyyy = 05 10 2008
4) yyyy dd MM =  2001 24 01
```

I want to convert all this dates to "yyyy-MM-dd" format

Currently, i am using

```
for (String eachFormat : formats) {
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(eachFormat);
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date inputDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(parsedDate.get(eachFormat));
        return targetFormat.format(inputDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e);
    }
}
```

but the "simpleDateFormat.parse()" will convert and give me date using timezone. I don't want timezone while converting. I want to straight up convert one date format to other. I am exploring LocalDate as java 8 feature. But it is failing if i try

```
DateTimeFormatter target = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(eachFormat);
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(parsedDate.get(eachFormat),target);
```

please help me with LocalDate and DateTimeFormatter.

Edit 1: ok, my bad for the typing Map example, here's the actually Map i am 
 getting in program

```
1) MM dd yy = 8 12 2019
2) dd MM yy = 4 5 2007
3) yy dd MM = 2001 10 8
```

I guess the person who is identifying and giving me this map is using SimpleDate formatter, because  i assume SimpleDateFormatter can identify the date "8 12 2019" as "MM dd yy" or "M dd yyyy" or "MM d yy" or "MM d yyyy"....

but "LocalDate" is very strict it is not parsing date

```
"8 12 2019" for "dd MM yy"
```

It strictly parse if and only if format of date

```
"8 12 2019" is "d MM yyyy"
```

...now what should i do?

Comment: "But it is failing" - Could you elaborate?

Comment: "throwing exceptions".... java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '9 9 2019' could not be parsed at index 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s correct, the old and troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` when parsing generally didn’t pay much attention to the number of pattern letters in the format pattern string. `DateTimeFormatter` does, which is generally an advantage since it allows for a much better validation of the string. `MM` requires two digits for month. `yy` requires a two-digit year (like 19 for 2019). Since you need to be able to parse one digit month and day of month and four digit year, I suggest that we modify the format pattern string to tell `DateTimeFormatter` exactly that. I am changing `MM` to `M`, `dd` to `d` and `yy` to `y`. This will cause `DateTimeFormatter` not to worry about the number of digits (one letter basically means *at least* one digit).

```
    Map<String, String> formattedDates = Map.of(
            "MM dd yy", "8 12 2019",
            "dd MM yy", "4 5 2007",
            "yy dd MM", "2001 10 8");

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : formattedDates.entrySet()) {
        String formatPattern = e.getKey();
        // Allow any number of digits for each of year, month and day of month
        formatPattern = formatPattern.replaceFirst("y+", "y")
                .replace("dd", "d")
                .replace("MM", "M");
        DateTimeFormatter sourceFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(formatPattern);
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(e.getValue(), sourceFormatter);
        System.out.format("%-11s was parsed into %s%n", e.getValue(), date);
    }
```

Output from this snippet is:

> ```
> 8 12 2019   was parsed into 2019-08-12
> 4 5 2007    was parsed into 2007-05-04
> 2001 10 8   was parsed into 2001-08-10
> ```

Comment: Thank you....working currently, will let you know if it fails...also i have added  .replace("M{2}", "M"); because i am also getting dd MMM yyyy

Comment: `MMM` is for month abbreviation (like `Sep` depending on locale). `.replace("M{2}", "M")` won’t replace anything because `replace` deosn’t understand regex. `.replaceFirst("M{2}", "M")` will change `MMM` to `MM`, which probably isn’t what you want. Try `.replaceFirst("\\bMM\\b", "M")`. It will leave `MMM` as it is but change `MM` to `M`.

Comment: omg....thank you again...Found out about that bug last min before build was about to go. Opened stackoverflow, and found your answer. I am glad i informed you....Phew