# How to format LocalDate to ISO 8601 with T and Z?

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-format, localdate, datetimeformatter

I'm trying to generate a random date and time, and convert it to the `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"` format.

Here is what I have tried:

```
  public static String generateRandomDateAndTimeInString() {
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.now().minus(Period.ofDays((new Random().nextInt(365 * 70))));
    System.out.println("date and time :: " + date.toString());
    return formatDate(date) ;
  }

  public static String formatDate(LocalDate date){
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
    return dateFormat.format(date);
  }
```

But in the line `dateFormat.format(date)`, it complains with:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date

The second problem is that, the output of print does not contain the time:

```
date :: 1998-12-24
```

I don't know how to get it to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing one date to another date format using LocalDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57791601/changing-one-date-to-another-date-format-using-localdate)

Comment: A `LocalDate` only has a day, a month and a year. If you want the time of day, too, think about a `LocalDateTime` and if you want an offset or a time zone, check out `OffsetDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime`. All of them may be parsed and formatted from/to `String` by means of a suitable `DateTImeFormatter`. No need for a `SimpleDateFormat` anymore...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Never format the `java.time` types using `SimpleDateFormat`

Using the `SimpleDateFormat`, you are supposed to format only legacy date-time types e.g. `java.util.Date`. In order to format the `java.time` date-time types, you need to use [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

### Never enclose `Z` within single quotes

It's a blunder to enclose `Z` within single quotes in a format. The symbol `Z` stands for `zulu` and specifies `UTC+00:00`. If you enclose it within single quotes, it will simply mean character literal, `Z` and won't function as `UTC+00:00` on parsing.

### You do not need to use a formatter explicitly

For this requirement, you do not need to use a formatter explicitly because the `OffsetDateTime#toString` already returns the string in the format that you need. However, if the number of **seconds** in an `OffsetDateTime` object is zero, the same and the subsequent smaller units are truncated by `OffsetDateTime#toString`. If you need the full format irrespective of the value of **seconds**, then, of course, you will have to use `DateTimeFormatter`.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(generateRandomDateAndTimeInString());
    }

    public static String generateRandomDateAndTimeInString() {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now().minus(Period.ofDays((new Random().nextInt(365 * 70))));
        System.out.println("date and time :: " + date.toString());
        return formatDate(date);
    }

    public static String formatDate(LocalDate date) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");
        // return date.atStartOfDay().atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toString();
        return date.atStartOfDay().atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(dtf);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
date and time :: 1996-09-05
1996-09-05T00:00:00Z
```

Note that the date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

- For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
- If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

### If you still need to use `SimpleDateFormat` for whatsoever reason:

Convert `LocalDate` to `ZonedDateTime` with `ZoneOffset.UTC` and at the start of the day ➡️ Convert `ZonedDateTime` to `Instant` ➡️ Obtain `java.util.Date` object from `Instant`.

```
public static String formatDate(LocalDate date) {
    Date utilDate = Date.from(date.atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant());
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");
    return dateFormat.format(utilDate);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, could you please write an answer using the `java.util.Calendar` which is newer?

Comment: `java.util.Calendar` is another hack on top of `java.util.Date`. I suggest you do not use it as you are already using the modern date-time API. Do not mix the error-prone `java.util` date-time API with it. If you insist, I can provide you with the same in a couple of minutes.

Comment: @Jeff - I've added a section at the end of my answer just because you have requested for it but as I have mentioned repeatedly, do not use `java.util` date-time API for any production code. They are error-prone and should never be mixed with the modern, `java.time` API. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt.

Comment: Newer? `java.util.Calendar` is a few years newer than `Date` alright but doesn’t really help us anything here since it cannot be formatted. `Calendar` is 24 years old and was supplanted nearly 7 years ago (March 2014) through java.time.

Comment: How can i do it, n a way that it generates random time as well?

Comment: @Jeff - Replace `return date.atStartOfDay().atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(dtf);` with `return date.atStartOfDay().plus(Duration.ofNanos(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(TimeUnit.DAYS.toNanos(1)))).atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(dtf);`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to ignore the time part then you can use `ZonedDateTime` like this:

```
DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
return ZonedDateTime.of(
        date, 
        LocalTime.MIN, 
        ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris")
).format(dateFormat);
```

**Output example**

```
2013-10-19T00:00:00+0200
```

Or much better, you can use just `toString` to get a formatted date as a String with the default format of `ZonedDateTime`:

```
return ZonedDateTime.of(
        date,
        LocalTime.MIN,
        ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris")
).toString();
```

**Output**

```
2013-10-19T00:00+02:00[Europe/Paris]
```

**Note**

This date are always with `00:00:00` for time part, because we are using `LocalTime.MIN`

Also, you can change the `ZoneId` to the expected `Zone`, this was just an example.

**Important**

`DateFormat` and `SimpleDateFormat` are legacy library, so please don't mix them with the `java.time` library, in the top you are using `LocalDate` which mean you are using this `java.time` library so keep going with it in all your code.

Comment: It's a blunder to enclose `Z` within single quotes in a format. Please correct it.

Comment: Thank you @LiveandLetLive I change it ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
    ZoneOffset utc = ZoneOffset.UTC;
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(utc);
    LocalDate seventyYearsAgo = today.minusYears(70);
    int totalDays = Math.toIntExact(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(seventyYearsAgo, today));
    LocalDate date = today.minusDays(new Random().nextInt(totalDays));
    String dateString = date.atStartOfDay(utc).toString();
    System.out.println("date and time :: " + dateString);
```

Example output:

> date and time :: 1983-08-24T00:00Z

Points to note:

- Let java.time convert from years to days. It gives more readable and more correct code (a year is not always 365 days).
- To have time of day and UTC offset in the string, convert a `ZonedDateTime` or an `OffsetDateTime` since such objects hold time of day and offset. A `LocalDate` does not. It’s a date without time of day and without offset from UTC. The `Z` you asked for denotes an offset of 0 from UTC.

If you want hours, minutes and seconds in the output too, you can have that by counting seconds rather than days. In this case use `OffsetDateTime` for the entire operation (or `ZonedDateTime` if in a time zone different from UTC).

```
    ZoneOffset utc = ZoneOffset.UTC;
    OffsetDateTime today = OffsetDateTime.now(utc).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
    OffsetDateTime seventyYearsAgo = today.minusYears(70);
    long totalSeconds = ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(seventyYearsAgo, today);
    OffsetDateTime date = today.minusSeconds(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(0, totalSeconds));
    String dateString = date.toString();
    System.out.println("date and time :: " + dateString);
```

> date and time :: 1996-09-21T06:49:56Z

I am using `ThreadLocalRandom` because it can generate a random long value in a specified interval. Funnily `ThreadLocalRandom` has a lot of convenient methods that `Random` hasn’t got.